# Filter registration with Spring Boot and Wicket AuthenticatedWebApplication

Tags: java, spring-boot, wicket

I am currently playing around with Apache Wicket 8 and Spring Boot. I made a simple web app with some panels, breandcrumbs dataprovider and so on. The app is working fine. In my Spring config class I've set up a Filter Bean. Now I want to implement authentication functionality. Hence I switched from extending Wickets WebApplication class to AuthenticatedWebApplication class and created a custom AuthenticatedWebSession.

When I now start the application I receive an `WicketRuntimeException` telling me to use `Application.init()` method to configure my application object. For some reason my Filter Bean cannot be instantiated anymore.

I tried to use a `FilterRegistrationBean` instead of `Filter` with the same effect.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Here is my config class with the `FilterRegistrationBean`:

```
@Configuration
@Import({PersistenceConfig.class})
public class SpringConfig {

// Either using Filter or FilterRegistrationBean is not working anymore

//  @Bean
//  public Filter getWicketFilter() {
//      WicketApplication webApplication = new WicketApplication();
//          webApplication.setConfigurationType(RuntimeConfigurationType.DEVELOPMENT);
//      WicketFilter filter = new WicketFilter(webApplication);
//      filter.setFilterPath("/");
//      return filter;
//
//  }

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<WicketFilter> wicketFilterRegistration(){
    WicketApplication webApplication = new WicketApplication();
        webApplication.setConfigurationType(RuntimeConfigurationType.DEVELOPMENT);

        WicketFilter filter = new WicketFilter(webApplication);
        filter.setFilterPath("/");

        FilterRegistrationBean<WicketFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
            registration.addInitParameter(WicketFilter.APP_FACT_PARAM,SpringWebApplicationFactory.class.getName());
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);

    return registration;
}

}
```

And here is the error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-07-24 08:43:32.601 ERROR 7052 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at eu.vrtime.bootwicketappthree.BootWicketApplication.main(BootWicketApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wicketFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [eu/vrtime/bootwicketappthree/config/SpringConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'wicketFilterRegistration' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Use Application.init() method for configuring your application object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:235) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:261) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5125) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:455) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'wicketFilterRegistration' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Use Application.init() method for configuring your application object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Use Application.init() method for configuring your application object
    at org.apache.wicket.Application.checkSettingsAvailable(Application.java:1322) ~[wicket-core-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Application.getSecuritySettings(Application.java:1274) ~[wicket-core-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.AuthenticatedWebApplication.init(AuthenticatedWebApplication.java:54) ~[wicket-auth-roles-8.0.0.jar:8.0.0]
    at eu.vrtime.bootwicketappthree.WicketApplication.<init>(WicketApplication.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at eu.vrtime.bootwicketappthree.config.SpringConfig.wicketFilterRegistration(SpringConfig.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at eu.vrtime.bootwicketappthree.config.SpringConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$70d9ab07.CGLIB$wicketFilterRegistration$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at eu.vrtime.bootwicketappthree.config.SpringConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$70d9ab07$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$73c80c3.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at eu.vrtime.bootwicketappthree.config.SpringConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$70d9ab07.wicketFilterRegistration(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

As the exception message suggests you need to call application.init() after instantiating it.

Comment: This is already done in my WicketApplication class by overriding the init method of AuthenticatedWebApplication and calling super.init()

Comment: You need to *call* the method, not just to override it.

Answer (score 1):

as Martin suggested you should do it in your FilterRegistrationBean definition, i.e.:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<WicketFilter> wicketFilterRegistration(){
WicketApplication webApplication = new WicketApplication();
    webApplication.setConfigurationType(RuntimeConfigurationType.DEVELOPMENT);
webApplication.init();//HERE!
```

BTW: consider to use the last 8.x version, which is 8.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your solution was not working. Same error was thrown again. However I was able to identify the problem at the end.

Problem was in constructor of my Wicket Application class. In this constructor I called super.init(). After removing this application started without Bean Instantiation error.

```
public class WicketApplication extends AuthenticatedWebApplication {

//  This caused the problem with instatiating the FilterRegistrationBean    
//  public WicketApplication() {
//      super.init();
//  }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        super.init();

        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));        
        mountPage("/admin", AdminPage.class);
        mountPage("/login", LoginPage.class);

    }


    @Override
    public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
        return AdminPage.class;
    }


    @Override
    protected Class<? extends AbstractAuthenticatedWebSession> getWebSessionClass() {
        return AppAuthenticatedWebSession.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends WebPage> getSignInPageClass() {
        return LoginPage.class;
    }

    public static WicketApplication get() {
        return (WicketApplication) Application.get();
    }

}
```